# Hand coded GUI build failed in Codename One

Tags: codenameone

In this project I started to create a form with the GUI Builder but I did not feel comfortable with this tool. Consequently I rather hand coded it based on a demo example https://github.com/codenameone/MaterialScreensUIKit/blob/master/src/com/codename1/uikit/materialscreens/LoginForm.java.

I should mention that I changed the name for the hand coded form from MainForm to MainForm2 and that I am using Netbeans with the latest availabel plugin of CN1 (updated November 7th 2016). Now for nearly each and every simulator run (when I click on the IDE play button) I get this error :

`ant -f /home/blablah/CN1Project -Dnb.internal.action.name=run run
Processing GUI builder file: /home/blablah/CN1Project/src/myPackage/MainForm.java
/home/blablah/CN1Project/build.xml:469: Gui builder source file corrupt, the don't edit below/above this line comments seem to be missing or modified!
 ErrCcode A: -1 ErrCode B: -1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)`

Line 469 reads :  `<generateGuiSources srcDir="src" encoding="UTF-8" guiDir="res/guibuilder"  />`

I understand the error message and I can confirm that the line comments is missing since I did create the form manually. Yet if I click a second time on the play button the simulator runs without error. Please note that the same behaviour also appears if I send build to CN1 server (two clicks needed).

What's the proper way of creating manually a Form (as shown in the demo codes), should I create it via new CN1/ GUI Builder Form or can I simply add the comments to make the compiling process happier ?

Any help appreciated,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your project directory look under `res/guibuilder` and in that hierarchy you will find a `.gui` file matching your java source file. Delete that and the file will stop being a GUI builder file.

Comment: That was it :-) ! Thanks @Shai!